# Access Data Project Error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a Access Data Project that connects to an SQL server database.  Recently I modified the structure of the database from the SQL server.  Now whenever I try to open one of the tables, I get the following error.

> Microsoft Office Access can't find the object 'SELECT *, sql_variant_property(value, 
>   'basetype') AS type FROM ::fn_listextendedproperty(N'MS_DisplayViewsOnSharePointSite',N'user',N'dbo',N'table',N'Hardware',NULL,NULL)'.
>
> - You misspelled the object name. Check for missing underscores ( _ ) or other punctuation, and make sure you didn't enter leading spaces.
> - You tried to open a linked table, but the file containing the table isn't on the path you specified. Use the Linked Table Manager to update the link and point to the correct path.

I tried to create a new access data project and see if it still happened there... and it does.

Comment: Whenever you make server-side design changes to tables or views that you have ODBC linked tables for, you are best advised to completely delete and recreate all the linked tables. Refreshing them doesn't reset all the metadata and they will often behave strangely (lack new columns, sort wrong, not return all records, be read-only, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently deleting the `MS_Filter` and `MS_OrderBy` extended properties on the table will resolve this.

**Source and instructions:** [Strange Microsoft Access Error on ADP project (Sql Server 2005 Extended Properties)](http://blog.dampee.be/post/2007/12/03/Strange-Microsoft-Access-Error-on-ADP-project-%28Sql-Server-2005-Extended-Properties%29.aspx)

Comment: This fixed the current error.... but then another popped up.  I dropped and re-created the table without the extended attributes and it fixed the issue.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I also had an invalid value for the `MS_DefaultView` property, so I deleted that one too. Now it displays perfectly. Thanks @Martin. :)

Comment: Weirdness.  I was getting this updating Form A (using DoCmd.SaveRecord) using table B, with sub form C referencing table D, and the error is for stored procedure F, which references table D, which is the table that has the extended properties on it

Answer (score 0):

We had this same error message come up after getting a weekend Severity21 error on the SQL DB backend.  The SQL DB was not having a problem but the Access front end did.  Deleting these 3 properties, MS_Filter, MS_OrderBy, and MS_DefaultView worked to resolve the error.  Note too that this error only showed up on one of about 20 tables via the Access front end.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all the Extended Properties, get Jamie Thompson’s script from

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/03/25/generate-drop-statements-for-all-extended-properties.aspx

Run it, copy the output and run that…