# The application on MS Access 2010 attacks SQL Server with service requests

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I observe the strange behavior of MS Access 2010.
There is a front-end application on MS Access 2010, which has been converted since version 2003. Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) database (KB4019093) - 12.0.5207.0 (X64). Connected to database with ADO, not ODBC.

After converting, the application began to send a large number of such requests to the database:

```
SELECT *, sql_variant_property (value, 'basetype') AS type 
FROM :: fn_listextendedproperty (
N'MS_Description ', N'user', N'dbo ', N'table', N'_ItemVariants', NULL, NULL)
```

They account for approximately 80% of all database requests. As a result, a catastrophic decline in productivity.

Probably someone has encountered a similar problem and will be able to help me disable sending such requests. Thank you.

P.S. The flow of these requests starts when the "DoCmd.Close acForm" command is executed.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516790/access-data-project-error

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Removing Extended properties does not solve the problem. The solve to the problem was to create a new form and transfer by copy-paste all the objects of the form and code. New forms don't post these requests. MS Terra incognita.